# Remove redundant space in HTML in JAVA

Tags: java, html, parsing, jtidy, htmlcleaner

Need to perform some HTML cleansing.

Have HTML that has lots of redundant br tags, so far tried HtmlCleaner and jTidy without any results.

Example:

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
...
```

What I would like is just to get a single `<br>` back

Any other ways to accomplish this without manually parsing line by line?

Comment: Be more specific. Like give some example HTML.

Comment: Its basically just a bunch of br tags repeated, want to replace with a single br. Just added more detail to the question.

Comment: you could send your html through an online minifier then do a mass replace i.e. http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Answer (score 0):

If your only trying to remove superfluous `<br/>` tags then I recommend a simple parsing state machine using [**Jericho**](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) to do the parsing since Jericho is very good about preserving data.

The state machine would simply keep the last tag seen and if the last tag seen is a `<br/>` tag and the next tag is a `<br/>` tag you simply omit it. Its a pretty simple exercise that I recommend you try. I don't recommend though manual text parsing (ie not using a HTML parser) as its very error prone.

I would also like to remind you that despite how people may use `<br/>` tags it is an explicit content tag. So removing the tag is changing the content. Perhaps instead of scraping some HTML you get the content from a more structured source like XML feed, REST API, or database, etc.

Comment: You're right that `<br />` is actually content. But I would state that it's sometimes a good thing removing newlines, just like one would trim a string from leading or trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Certain legal documents and regulated specifications require specific white spacing. As a user inputting documents I would find it annoying if you stripped my explicit new lines. This is different then trimming input on a single field like a title field.

Comment: It is, @AdamGent. But even StackOverflow seems to do it. In this very comment,
for example,
newlines *are* removed from the comment. (I have newlines before and after *'for example'*. They are still there if I edit the comment, but they're not visible.)